# Forgot password in Ubuntu console

Tags: 20.04, password

I have Ubuntu 20.04 app from MS store version on my Windows 10 Enterprise machine and in order to install a software ([docksal](https://docs.docksal.io/getting-started/setup/)), with normal user I am able to see a prompt like this tan@MyComputername and in order to install Docksal, it's asking me to use sudo password for tan but all of my password attempts were unsuccessful.

On the other hand, if I start the ubuntu console using administrator, it ran find and I was able to install the docksal. But I want to do it with regular user with sudo command. How can I fix this password issue which is not working? I have tried putting the administrator password when it asks for password but that didn't work.

**EDITED ( Added more information):**

After opening Ubuntu Console in Administrator mode it asked me to create a username as shown in the below and set my own password and it worked for installation.

[image]

However, when I opened it with normal user, it didn't ask for creating a username as far as I remember and was asking for sudo password later on to proceed which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that using the console as the admin puts you as the super user, you can use `passwd YOURUSERNAME(tan)` to change your user (probably `tan`)'s password and then use that for `sudo`.